# How to use mediainfo on aws s3 filname contain space?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mediainfo

How to use mediainfo on aws s3 filename contain space?

I got this error.
 E: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/video/batmanvs superman.mov, 
 
 `HttpVersionNotSupported`The HTTP version specified is not supported.

I tried single quote and double quote.
mediainfo 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/video/batmanvs superman.mov'

I got the same error.

But if the filename without spacing it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your command with double quotes is the one to use.

MediaInfo bug, I guess.
I'll look at it (I did not try with a space in the file name, and the code is internal, without using AWS SDK, not a lot tested).
If you don't mind, please [open a ticket](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib).

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo